# Linux Mint 20.3 MonoDevelop runtime error - Hello World

Tags: c#, .net, monodevelop, linux-mint

I am new to Linux. I have installed MonoDevelop and created my first program to test. It's getting build but while executing giving error 'cannot execute /home/nidhi.... MyFirstProject.exe'. Please help.

[image]

Comment: I see a few post suggesting to install xterm... (`sudo apt install xterm` in your terminal) - gnome-terminal is another option. This is a little surprising but it seems worth a try too...

Comment: I have tried xterm and gnome both but still it is same.

Comment: Hmm weird. Well I'm out of ideas. But if you are open to a completely different option, I think C# + Visual Studio Code is the future of C# on Linux (as far as free and still very good IDE's). I don't believe this monodevelop IDE is still even actively maintained.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-monodevelop-80b383dab34b Don't waste your time on a dead product.